# Pandas Converting CSV to Parquet - String having , not able to convert

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pip, pyarrow

I am using Pandas to Convert CSV to Parquet  and below is the code, it is straight Forward.

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path/xxxx.csv')
print(df)
df.to_parquet('path/xxxx.parquet')

### Problem

In a String for Example :- David,Johnson. If there is a , getting error saying there is a problem in the data.
If i remove the , the CSV File is converting to Parquet.

Any suggesions, need help

Thanks
Madhu

If i remove the , the CSV File is converting to Parquet

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to keep comma in the name of the file? Otherwise you can do `input='David,Johnson'`, `output=input.replace(',','_')`. I don't think it is generally a good practice to have comma in your file names.

Comment: Yes i need the Comma,I don't want to replace comma, If the field has David,Johnson then in the Converted File the output should be David,Johnson